# Why is my program only appending every other input into my list?

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to create a python program that takes multiple lines from the user and adds them to a list. Inputting a blank line ends the program and returns the list. However only every other line is being added to the list. If anyone could help that would be great.

```
def read_lines():
 lines = []
 contin = True
 while contin:
  if len(input()) == 0:
   contin = False
  else:
   lines.append(input())
  return(lines)
```

There is my code here is what is happening:

```
>>> read_lines()
abc
def
ghi
jkl

['def', 'jkl']
```

Comment: every other line is lost by testing its length!!!

Comment: Does my explanation answer your doubt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you call it *twice* for each iteration. You call it once for the `len` check, and once for the `append`. Each time, it extracts a new string from the command line. Consider calling it once and storing the result in a variable, at the top of your loop. Then do your `len` and `append` operations on that stored result.

Comment: Oh of course that's a silly mistake! Thanks for the help

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the answer if it answered your question @T.Huber

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `input` with the `if` statement, it will get the input from the user. Suppose you enter a valid string, then the length will not be zero and the `if` block will not be executed. So, you go to `else` block where you again get a new input from the user; This discards the previous input that you got since you did not store it in any variable. Thus, for each valid input you give only the alternate elements are appended to the list.

Your code will append all the input you enter into the list when you alternately press `enter` key and a valid input in the same order.

I have added the correct code here:

```
def read_lines():
    lines = []
    contin = True
    while contin:
        string = input()
        if len(string) == 0:
            contin = False
        else:
            lines.append(string)
    return(lines)
```